# How to exclude an input number within a range from calculating the highest number and average?

Tags: java

In my program, I'm trying to have the user input an undetermined amount of grades, between 0 and 100, where if it's below 0 or over 100, it has an error message, until the user inputs "999", then displaying the number of grades entered, the highest number, lowest number, and the average.

I have everything in the program working, however I can't figure out how to exclude the "999" that ends the user being able to input numbers from the highest grade, and the average.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScoreStatistics
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int numberOfScores = 0;
  int highest = 0;
  int lowest = 100;
  double average;
  Integer score = 0;
  int sumOfScores = 0;

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Please enter a grade or enter 999 to finish >> ");
  score = input.nextInt();
  sumOfScores = sumOfScores + score;


     while (score != 999 && score <= 100 && score >= 0)
     {

      System.out.println("Please enter a grade or enter 999 to finish >> ");
      score = input.nextInt();
      sumOfScores = sumOfScores + score;
      ++numberOfScores;
      if(score > highest){
      highest=score;}
      else if(score<lowest){
      lowest=score;}
     }
        while (score != 999 && score > 100 || score < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("You entered an invalid score. Please enter a valid test score.");
            System.out.println("Please enter a grade or enter 999 to finish >> ");
            score = input.nextInt();
            sumOfScores = sumOfScores + score;

        }
             if (score == 999)
             {
             System.out.println("Number of Scores you entered: " + numberOfScores);
             System.out.println("Highest Score: " + highest);
             System.out.println("Lowest Score: " + lowest);
             average = sumOfScores / numberOfScores;
             System.out.println("Average Score: " + average);
             }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two extra loops, I would start with an infinite loop, check for `999` and validity and then increment the values (and update `highest` and `lowest` and etc). Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numberOfScores = 0, highest = 0, lowest = 100;
    int sumOfScores = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a grade or enter 999 to finish >> ");
        int score = input.nextInt();
        if (score == 999) {
            break; // <-- end the loop
        } else if (score > 100 || score < 0) {
            System.out.println("You entered an invalid score. " 
                    + "Please enter a valid test score.");
        } else {
            sumOfScores += score;
            numberOfScores++;
            highest = Math.max(highest, score);
            lowest = Math.min(lowest, score);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of Scores you entered: " + numberOfScores);
    System.out.println("Highest Score: " + highest);
    System.out.println("Lowest Score: " + lowest);
    double average = sumOfScores / (double) numberOfScores;
    System.out.println("Average Score: " + average);
}
```